# mediaplayer not working

Tags: java, android, audio

I am create media player. Its display songs in `listview` but when I click the song. The log cat show this error:

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(songPath);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

logcat error:

```
11-15 19:12:32.250: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('/sdcardparatha.mp3')
11-15 19:12:32.289: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2515): error (1, -2147483648)
11-15 19:12:32.289: VERBOSE/song(2515): Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course thats not going to work since you set your resource to be `/sdcardparatha.mp3` whereas you meant `/sdcard/paratha.mp3`.